# Aurelia-bundler: Transpile jspm depenencies during bundling

Tags: aurelia

I have a problem with bundling my JSPM dependencies using aurelia-bundler. One of my dependencies uses ES6 arrow functions which causes an error during minifcation of the bundle when uglify is executed.

I wonder what the correct way is to resolve this issue in my build. I presume that I need to configure aurelia-bundler to transpile this dependency during bundling in order to make uglify work. But I have no idea how this configuration might look?

Comment: I've seen a setup for react that uses typescript->babel->the rest.
You might want to look that way.
What's the dependency that uses only ES6 distribution? How do they suggest to use it?

Comment: The dependency is `https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-request-token` but they don't say anything about how to use it. Do you have a link that describes how to setup such a build or how to incorporate the babel transpiling into the aurelia-bundler?

Comment: maybe you needed this one?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-js

Comment: No, I actually need `npm:keycloak-admin-client` and `npm:keycloak-request-token` is a dependency of it...

Comment: admin client looks like a node only.. not meant for browser

Comment: I suggest you raise a question @ keycloak.. on how to use it in the browser..

Comment: If you want to switch your app to use aurelia-cli, I think I can help you to update aurelia.json transpiler config to make this work. With cli, if you build in default dev environment, ugilify is bypassed, you should able to run at least in dev right now. If you made the switch, let me know your jspm or npm package name, then I can help you on modifying aurelia.json config file.

Comment: @huocp I am already able to run this in dev without uglification. But I want to deploy my app so it would be nice to get rid of the ES6 features and to enable uglification.

Comment: I mean you are using aurelia-bundler not aurelia-cli. With aurelia-cli, it's possible to modify aurelia.json transpiler section to force babel preprocessing on the file. It probably needs some adjustment on dependencies section, I need to test it out if you provide that jspm package name.